# Unable to store data through HTTP GET request - potentially Observable / Asynchronous order issue

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I'm calling a Service from an onSubmit(). The service then calls a REST API for data. However the ordering is not what I'd expect.
I think I have 2 issues here:

1. The log `@@@ CUSTOMER BEFORE RETURN` doesn't seem to contain the retrieved data despite initialising the variable at the start of the method. So at this log line, it's still `undefined`. However at `@@@ UNPACKED DATA` the data is visible.
2. Even if `customer` was not undefined at the return of `loadCustomer`, it looks like the line `@@@ CUSTOMER IN onSubmit` is executed before data is retrieved and not after, which will be a problem since I need to use the data afterwards!

```
  onSubmit(customerData) {
    let customer = this.customerService.loadCustomer(customerData)
    console.log("@@@ CUSTOMER IN onSubmit", customer)

    // use customer Object to process orders...
  }
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    loadCustomer(customerId: number) {
        console.log("@@@ Customer ID to get: ", customerId)
        var myStr: string;
        var myObj: any;
        var customer: Object

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        };

        this.http.get<any[]>('https://REGION.amazonaws.com/dev/customer', httpOptions).subscribe(
            data => {

                myStr = JSON.stringify(data);
                myObj = JSON.parse(myStr);

                console.log("@@@ UNPACKED DATA", myObj['data']['Items'][customerId-1])
                if (typeof myObj['data']['Items'][customerId] != "undefined")
                    customer = myObj['data']['Items'][customerId-1]

            },
            error => console.log('Failed to get customer.')
        );

        console.log("@@@ CUSTOMER BEFORE RETURN: ", customer)

        return customer;

    }
```

```
OUTPUT IN CONSOLE:
customer.service.ts:21 @@@ Customer ID to get:  2
customer.service.ts:51 @@@ CUSTOMER BEFORE RETURN:  undefined
cart.component.ts:64 @@@ CUSTOMER IN onSubmit undefined
customer.service.ts:38 @@@ UNPACKED DATA {customer_id: 2, address: "32 Big avenue", row_id: "a97de132-89ac-4f6e-89cd-2005319d5fce", name: "Dave Lawinski", tel_number: "777888999"}
```

From what I've gathered this looks like something to do with `Observable` / some form of asynchronous operation, however I've not been able to make sense of where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Thanks for this - sorry it doesn't quite fix it. So from that post I understand that the `subscribe` function is what's 'asynchronous'. So I tried returning `customer` from within the `subscribe()`, but it still calls the `@@@ CUSTOMER IN onSubmit ` line before getting data and not after, therefore the output is essentially the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning an object before the http call returns, you need to return an observable and then subscribe to it in the component:

```
onSubmit(customerData) {
  this.customerService.loadCustomer(customerData)
    .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("@@@ CUSTOMER IN onSubmit", res)
        // use res Object to process orders...
    })
}
```

and in your `loadCustomer` function:

```
loadCustomer(customerId: number) {
  const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
  };

  return this.http.get<any[]>('https://REGION.amazonaws.com/dev/customer', httpOptions)
    .pipe(map((result) => {
        const myStr = JSON.stringify(data);
        const myObj = JSON.parse(myStr);
        let customer; 

        console.log("@@@ UNPACKED DATA", myObj['data']['Items'][customerId-1])
        if (typeof myObj['data']['Items'][customerId] != "undefined") {
            customer = myObj['data']['Items'][customerId-1];
        }
        
        return customer;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However I'm getting an `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'` error when trying to use that `map` function. I've imported `import { map } from "rxjs/operators";` but still hasn't resolved it. I'm running Angular 9.0.2 on this project

Comment: @solarflare, sorry, my mistake, ive updated the question, you need to add a pipe operator before the map

Comment: Ah ok thank you - so I'm actually still getting undefined for `customer` within the onSubmit.
Mine is actually different - so I have `res` being logged out instead of `customer` since that was giving me an error, but then `res` still shows up as undefined
This is probably because `customer` if logged directly after `customer = myObj['data']['Items'][customerId-1];` is also undefined!

Comment: yes you are right, you should log res, and not customer, in `onSubmit`, when you log customer just before returning it in the map operator, is it undefined?

Comment: It is yes, so even in that if-block it's still undefined which is very strange. The `@@@ UNPACKED DATA` returns the data fine. So maybe it has some issue with storing this data within the variable `customer`?

Comment: how about in `loadCustomer`, if you add console.log(customer) before returning it, does it have a value there?

Comment: Ah sorry my fault - somehow was passing an incorrect customerId which wasn't returning any results! Thank you very much it's working as expected now :)